# How to relate additional tables to Auth::user

Tags: laravel

On documentation of Laravel, to retrieve the authenticated user:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

This is my table schema (example)

```
tblUser
   id // 1
   userid // admin
   password // 12345

tblUserInfo
   id // 1
   userid // admin
   first_name // Roi
```

Is it possible to relate the `tblUserInfo` for the authenticated user? like for example

`Auth::user()->with('userinfo')->first_name;`

or is there a way around to get the first_name from authenticated user before I hit the view?

Comment: Read more relationship in laravel here

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: you should have asked me instead lol

Comment: Lol wtf, i pmed u on facebook u never reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just do

```php
$firstname = Auth::user()->userinfo->first_name;
```

This assumes you have your relationship defined properly. Something along the lines of

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    public function userinfo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserInfo::class);
    }
}
```

*Given your non-standard table schema you may need to explicitly specify column names for foreign and local keys in `hasOne()` method - 2nd and 3rd parameters accordingly.*

```php
    return $this->hasOne(UserInfo::class, 'id', 'id'); // or 'userid' depending on what you're using as a FK
                                           ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it before and didn't work, but now it works